# Can not register custom renderer for Handsontable in angular 5,No registered renderer found under

Tags: javascript, angular, handsontable

I prepared a custom renderer for Handsontable in angular 5 but i can not find a way to register the renderer.I can not find any function like 'registerRenderer'.Renderer function is specified below

```
coverRenderer (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties):any 
{
 var escaped = Handsontable.helper.stringify(value),
  button;

  button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  button.setAttribute("name","Edit");
  //button.onclick = this.editFood(value);
  Handsontable.dom.addEvent(button, 'click',  () => {       
    this.editFood(value);
  });

  Handsontable.dom.empty(td);
  td.appendChild(button);
  return td;
}
```

When i load the table it show error like "No registered renderer found under "coverRenderer" name". How can i register the renderer . I am using angular 5

Comment: can someone tell me "how to create a custom renderer and register it in angular 5 handsontable wrapper ?"

Answer (score 1):

After hours of tries, I did not found a way to register a new renderer. So I tried, when declaring the renderer of the table (I use columns object), something like this.

In my html I have:

```
<hot-table [data]="data" [colHeaders]="true" [columns]="columns"></hot-table>
```

In my component this portion of code

```
columns: object[] = [
    { data: 'data.rowName', readOnly: true, renderer: this.rowRendering},
    { data: 'data.baseInitialMargin'},
]

rowRendering(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    console.log("Rendering row ");
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    if(row % 2 == 0) {
        td.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5';
    } else {
        td.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
}
```

And it works fine for me, I see the pair rows of my column with a different color. After a lot of blasphemy!

Comment: thank you.can you render a button and can you make a function call on button trigger? function should be in angular component.

Answer (score 0):

in your template you should write

```
 <hot-column (data="{{row}}", title="{{row}}",[renderer]="tableOptions.options.renderer" )></hot-column>
```